# Input.GetKeyDown registering multiple times in one key press C# UNITY

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Pressing "a" with Input.GetKeyDown seems to register multiple times, is it because of the switch case with the enum i have going on? below is the first script where the GameState is "Player select action" if "a" is pressed in the gamestate "Player select action, it wont just print "Game State is Player Attack Unit" but it will also activate all the the code in the second script even though im using Input.GetKeyDown, how can i make it so that pressing the "a" key once only changes the gamestate and doesnt activate all the code in the second script?

1st script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Threading;

public enum GameState
{
    PlayerSelectTile,
    PlayerSelectAction,
    PlayerMoveUnit,
    PlayerPreviewAttackUnit,
    PlayerAttackUnit,
    EnemyTurn,
    GameOver,
    Convoy
}

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameState CurrentState;

    void Start()
    {
        CurrentState = GameState.PlayerSelectTile;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        switch (CurrentState)
        {
            case GameState.PlayerSelectAction:

                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
                {
                    CurrentState = GameState.PlayerAttackUnit;
                    Debug.Log("Game State is Player Attack Unit");
                }
                
                break;

            case GameState.PlayerAttackUnit:

                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
                {
                    CurrentState = GameState.PlayerSelectAction;
                    Debug.Log("Game State is Player Select Action");
                }

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

2nd script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Threading;

public enum UFA
{
    None,
    Alm,
    Chrom
}

public enum EFA
{
    None,
    Alm,
    Chrom
}

public class Attacking : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int USFAbaseATK;
    public static int USFAbaseDEF;
    public static string USFAclass;
    public static int ESFAbaseATK;
    public static int ESFAbaseDEF;
    public static string ESFAclass;
    public static int USFAnetDMG;
    public static int ESFAnetDMG;
    public static int USFAbaseHP;
    public static int ESFAbaseHP;
    public static int USFAprevHP;
    public static int ESFAprevHP;
    public static int USFAnetHP;
    public static int ESFAnetHP;
    public static int USFAbaseSPD;
    public static int ESFAbaseSPD;
    public static string USFAname;
    public static string ESFAname;
    public static int SPDkey;
    public static UFA USFA;
    public static EFA ESFA;

    void Start()
    {
        USFA = UFA.None;
        ESFA = EFA.None;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        switch (GameController.CurrentState)
        {
            case GameState.PlayerAttackUnit:

                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
                {
                    if (USFA == UFA.Alm)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Unit selected for attack is Alm, class " + USFAclass + ", base attack " + USFAbaseATK + ", base def " + USFAbaseDEF);
                        SPDkey = USFAbaseSPD - ESFAbaseSPD;

                        if (SPDkey > 0)
                        {
                            USFAnetDMG = 2 * (USFAbaseATK - ESFAbaseDEF);
                            ESFAnetDMG = 1 * (ESFAbaseATK - USFAbaseDEF);
                        }

                        if (SPDkey == 0)
                        {
                            USFAnetDMG = 1 * (USFAbaseATK - ESFAbaseDEF);
                            ESFAnetDMG = 1 * (ESFAbaseATK - USFAbaseDEF);
                        }

                        if (SPDkey < 0)
                        {
                            USFAnetDMG = 1 * (USFAbaseATK - ESFAbaseDEF);
                            ESFAnetDMG = 2 * (ESFAbaseATK - USFAbaseDEF);
                        }

                        if (ESFA == EFA.None)
                        {
                            USFAnetDMG = 0;
                            ESFAnetDMG = 0;
                        }

                        USFAprevHP = USFAnetHP - ESFAnetDMG;
                        ESFAprevHP = ESFAnetHP - USFAnetDMG;

                        Debug.Log(USFAname + ": HP - " + USFAbaseHP + " --> " + USFAprevHP + " | " + ESFAname + ": HP - " + ESFAbaseHP + " --> " + ESFAprevHP + " A to confirm attack");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click a button, you click that button on a certain ***frame***, and every frame (for example ~60 frames per second) is represented by the `Update()` method. This means that when you click the button `A`, every `Update()` method will have `GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) == true` for that frame and the next frame it will be false in every `Update()` method.

You will need to structure your code so that only one thing can happen at the time, for example by setting a requirement that the gamestate must have been the same for at least two frames for certain actions. To achieve this you need to keep 2 state variables, one with `currentState`(like you have today) but also set `previousState` and then check...

```
if (previousState == x && currentState == x) 
{
   // Do thing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using LateUpdate for the 1st script, and make sure that PlayerAttackUnit is not the default GameState.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html

Comment: This could also work, although arguably a bit hackier and less obvious for a future reader of the code! +1 tho