# GetKeyDown always returning true resulting stackoverflow

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am wrapping up GetKeyDown into a function as below:

```cs
class PlayerInputHandler{

    public static bool TestPInput()
    {
        bool k = GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P);
        return k;
    }
}
```

and calling in a update function as

```cs
void HandleTestInput()
{
    if (PlayerInputHandler.TestPInput())
    {
        Debug.Log("Pressed p");
        HandleTestInput();
    }
}
```

In my Update as:

```cs
void Update()
{
    HandleTestInput();
}
```

**Q1. How is this going into an infinite Loop ?**
as I have strictly given the condition

```cs
if (PlayerInputHandler.TestPInput())
```

Also how can this always return true ?

 as on the next call, it should be rechecking the input right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Input.GetKeyDown registering multiple times in one key press C# UNITY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68277277/input-getkeydown-registering-multiple-times-in-one-key-press-c-sharp-unity)

Comment: I were having some doubt but with the below explanation, it was much clearer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Input.GetKeyDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html)

> Returns true **during the frame** the user starts pressing down the key identified by the key KeyCode enum parameter.

This means as long as you are in the same frame this still returns `true`!

Your issue has little to do with the input itself but rather the fact that `HandleTestInput` is calling `HandleTestInput` and between these two calls no frame passes

=> There is no way that `GetKeyDown` returns a different value within the same frame.

This is not really an infinite loop though, but rather will throw a `StackOverflowException` after enough recursion.

---

If you rather actually wanted to do something **while** the key stays pressed you rather want to use [`Input.GetKey`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html)

> Returns true while the user holds down the key identified by the key KeyCode enum parameter.

like e.g.

```c#
class PlayerInputHandler
{
    public static bool TestPInput()
    {
        return GetKey(KeyCode.P);
    }
}
```

and then

```c#
private void HandleTestInput()
{
    if(PlayerInputHandler.TestPInput())
    {
        // In general do NOT log something every frame!
        Debug.Log("p is pressed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought GetKeyDown gets calculated everytime when it is called. But calculated once per frame instead.

Comment: If so, if we want to calculate multiple number of inputs of a particular key code  in one frame, is it not a recommended practice ?

Comment: also GetKey behaves in the similar way